# Uninstalling Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uninstallation, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to uninstall Visual Studio Community 2015. It has been hanging on the Preparation step for at least 12 hours. (Left it going over night). I did not want to cancel since I thought it might just be running slowly but now I am thinking that it is stuck. I have also tried repairing and it does the same thing.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Hi Christopher, have you tried the following uninstall methods and it works or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely uninstall the VS community 2015, you can have a look at [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/) and try to forcibly uninstall through the command like vs_community.exe **/uninstall /force**. It can forcibly remove almost all components.

There also have a **visual studio uninstaller tool** to cleanup/scorch all Preview/RC/RTM releases of Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio vNext. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller).

If the uninstall still failed, you use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.